# Rails Puma Mail Erro port for ni

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Error:

```
*telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 ok
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 ok
Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 2
```

Configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'rapid.virus.0@gmail.com',
  password:             '55xxxxxx',
  authentication:        :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: some tips: if you ask the question don't put email password inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two things you can do hopefully can fix your problem with "connection refused"

- find your IP from [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/) and then put it to this line, (gmail cannot accept localhost:3000)

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' }
```

- if you want to use gmail account you have to put gmail with less secure with this https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  and turned on so your application can use it.